# Is it possible to register two actions within one <intent-filter> for Activity

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter

I wanted to register my launcher activity so it could be started by both clicking on icon and opening link with a custom scheme. I managed to make it work but am questioning is this correct way. This is the relevant part of my manifest:

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="my.sheme" />
        </intent-filter>
```

This does work but I was wondering should I register both actions under same intent filter. I tried just moving tags from second filter to the first one but then my activity doesn't show icon on install. Is it possible to do it this way and I just made some small syntax error(or broke some undocumented order of declaration rule) or is my thinking completely wrong on this and there are deeper reasons why this doesn't work?

NOTE:I do set android:exported="true"but android.intent.action.MAIN works even without it because it becomes exported anyway if you use action.MAIN

Comment: two intent filters is the path you should follow

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving) states:

> When you want to handle multiple kinds of intents, but only in specific combinations of action, data, and category type, then you need to create multiple intent filters.

Otherwise you can group them into one intent-filter.

Comment: I missed that paragraph so thank you for reference. So that actually means you can have only one action under intent filter?

Comment: No, you can have multiple actions. But they need to match any combination with a category. An action `android.intent.action.VIEW` with a category `android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: On the [linked documentation page](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving) there is an example with multiple actions in an intent-filter: `android.intent.action.SEND` and `android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE`

Comment: I am still not 100% clear about the multiple actions in one filter but the page referenced in this answer is the right source of data for this. Unfortunately explanations on that page are a bit convoluted but I am experimenting now based on those so this seems like the right answer.