# Intent-Filter: Using two actions along with Launcher and Browsable category

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter, deep-linking

TL;DR Can i use two actions and two categories in one intent-filter?

My app is made up of one activity and five fragments. I have an Intent Filter in this activity.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Today, I saw a lint message "App is not indexable by Google..." around the `application` tag in manifest file. So, I did some searching and came to know that you can use this to index your app through google search. If an android user browses web link "www.example.com/myapp" from chrome/systemBrowser, he will be taken to my app instead of web page. right?

Now, I have to add an ActionView to the activity. and, my intent-filter will become,

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" android:pathPrefix="/myapp" />
 </intent-filter>
```

But, I have read that using two actions is not good. It is a Logical OR operation. Intent-Filter will match only one of them:

- 1. an intent with MAIN action and LAUNCHER Category
- 2. an intent with MAIN action and BROWSABLE Category
- 3. an intent with VIEW action and LAUNCHER Category
- 4. an intent with VIEW action and BROWSABLE Category

As i understand it, It should open app on device with first option, and when a user browses the browser with provided "www.example.com/myapp", it should use first and fourth option to open the app from link.

I have looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564510/), but i need to be sure with an example.

It is confusing. I might be entirely wrong, please guide me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By the help of someone from SO Chat, I was told to use separate `intent-filters`

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" android:pathPrefix="/prefix" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```